# Creating a Procedure Error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search
@id INT

AS
BEGIN
SET NO COUNT ON;
SELECT  cteachID,
        cfname,
        cmname,
        clname
FROM tbl_teacher
WHERE cteachID = @id
END
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@id INT AS BEGIN SET NO COUNT ON' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the MariaDB documentation on stored procedures here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-procedure/

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE search
(IN id INT)
BEGIN

    SELECT  cteachID,
            cfname,
            cmname,
            clname
    FROM tbl_teacher
    WHERE cteachID = id;

END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

In addition to this, you need to use the delimiter keyword, since your create procedure uses begin/end blocks.

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/stored-procedure-overview/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delimiters/

Comment: I think mysql doesn't have "SET NO COUNT ON;" command it need to replace by something equivalent

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức Good point; completely missed that line.  Emended

Answer (score 0):

You code is work for sql sever. For mysql, syntax of store procedured have some difference

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS search;

    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE search(IN id INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  cteachID,
                cfname,
                cmname,
                clname
                    FROM tbl_teacher
                    WHERE cteachID = id;
    END$$

    DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Do you create it using phpmyadmin ? And if you can please post error message when you run my answer

Comment: yes i run it with phpmyadmin heres the error

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: For phpmyadmin, I often get error caused by delimiter when create store procedure and function. I have updated answer and can you retry it

Comment: Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Expected delimiter. (near "" at position 10)
SQL query:

DELIMITER;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1